# Change values in a csv with PS according to predefined values

Tags: powershell, csv, export

Hello fellow Stackoverflowers,

once again, I am stuck at a certain problem which I hope can be solved with PS:

A GIS program puts out lines in the following form into a csv:

```
"House 5";9660.7734;1782.7454;0;0;
"House 9";9675.0684;1779.7888;0;0;
"House 8";9675.0684;1779.7888;0;0;
"House 2";9688.3779;1777.323;0;0;
"House 12";9709.5742;1772.3938;0;0;
"House 11";9709.5742;1772.3938;0;0;
"House 12";9734.2217;1771.4075;0;0;
"House 8";9755.9111;1770.4211;0;0;
"House 5";9779.0801;1770.9155;0;0;
"House 7";9779.0801;1770.9155;0;0;
"House 2";9802.7412;1770.9155;0;0;
```

and so on....

I would like to keep that form but change each line's value after the 3rd semicolon (here **0**) to values that are speficied by each line's 1st value (**House XX**). The values to be applied are **15** for *House 5*, **12** for *House 8*, **8** to *House 2* and **3** to *House 12*.

Also, there are "Houses" in the list that dont have to be changed: *House 9*, *House 11* and *House 7*.In the end , the output file (again csv) should look like this:

```
"House 5";9660.7734;1782.7454;15;0;
"House 9";9675.0684;1779.7888;0;0;
"House 8";9675.0684;1779.7888;12;0;
"House 2";9688.3779;1777.323;8;0;
"House 12";9709.5742;1772.3938;3;0;
"House 11";9709.5742;1772.3938;0;0;
"House 12";9734.2217;1771.4075;3;0;
"House 8";9755.9111;1770.4211;12;0;
"House 5";9779.0801;1770.9155;15;0;
"House 7";9779.0801;1770.9155;0;0;
"House 2";9802.7412;1770.9155;8;0;
```

So, when I provide the changevalues for all the different "Houses" (could also use a list), can a PS script save me the work of manual changing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So It's hollidays here, but I feel like doing sombody's homework :

```
Import-Csv yourfile.csv -Delimiter ';' -header 'a','b','c','d','e' | % {$a=$_;switch -regex ($_.a) {.*5 {$a.d=15} .*8 {$a.d=12} "House 12" {$a.d=3} "House 2" {$a.d=8}};$_}
```

You can pipe to export-csv.